# I need to remove the rel attribute mean value from script and instead the image id or any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove the rel value from script and instead the image id or any value i mean some way to generator rel attribute or remove or just make some way to avoid this attribute

HTML

Text Here
      
        CLOSE X

```
<article class="col img_prev2">
  <img src="img/slideshow/slideshow2.jpg" alt="#img2" rel="1" class="thumb_main_page">
  <h5>Text Here</h5>
</article>

<article class="col img_prev2">
  <img src="img/slideshow/slideshow3.jpg" alt="#img2" rel="2" class="thumb_main_page">
   <h5>Text Here</h5>

  <div id="img3" class="login-popup">
  </div>

</article>
```

Script

```
var number = $(this).attr('rel');
    number = parseInt(number);
    $('#carousel .slides li:nth-child(' + (number + 1) + ')').click();
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 105,
        itemMargin: 5,
        startAt: number,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
    });
```

Comment: You want to remove the `rel` attribute, but you are using it.  Do you want to remove it after it is used by the carousel?  Please edit the question and clarify what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### jQuery `.removeAttr()`

> **Description**: Remove an attribute from each element in the set of matched elements.
> <sup>1</sup>

In your case, the most basic form would be:

```
$(img).removeAttr('rel');
```

<sup>1</sup> http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: When I remove the attribute the images not appear so i need some way to make this attribute on script only and remove from HTML

Comment: When you remove the attribute...how? Manually before the page loads? Or with the script above? Nothing about the existence of the `rel` property should affect the appearance of an `<img>`.